# Laravel Model appending Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have created a Model in laravel for a table `celebrity` and have created two objects like below:-

```
$obj1 = Celebrity::Select('*');
$obj2 = $obj1;
```

Now, I want to apply different condition for above objects to get data from the table. For example:-

```
$obj1= $obj1->where('status', 1);

$obj2 = $obj2->where('status', 2);
```

But When obj2 returns both the Query. i.e. If I print `$obj2->toSQL()`, it is `'Select * from celebrity where stauts =1 and status =2'`. But it should be  `'Select * from celebrity where  status =2'`.

can any one help on this? And I am using version 5.5.

Comment: can u show how u are obj2->tosql();

Comment: The 'O' is small in `$obj1` where it is capital in `$obj2` when you add `where` conditions in them. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Jigs1212, if i print obj2->tosql(); its printing   Select * from celebrity where stauts =1 and status =2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to create objects. You can simply do this in your controller:

```
$a = Celebrity::where(['status' => '1'])->get();
$b = Celebrity::where(['status' => '2'])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks , @prit.patel , my Question , i have mentioned is for an example. my problem is my query is appending when even print second object it appends the first object condtion too

Comment: So are you just asking why that is happening or you want a solution for that? @user

Comment: Yes, i need to know, why its happening , and how to avoid this

Comment: @prit.patel your code have an error on wheres, this is a correct form  
 `Celebrity::where('status', 1)->get();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

Comment: No it's correct. You can try it. It is just a different form.@sk11z00

Comment: Frankly i don't know why it is happening but my solution will atleast avoid it.@user

Comment: @prit.patel thanks you that me have toknown a new form to add conditions on laravel.

Comment: @sk11z00 You are welcome. I got used to this form because it's used in other type of statements too. For ex.- Insert, Update, etc

Comment: @prit.patel , i have updated the Question to explaining what exactly i have faced

Comment: @user try to execute this `$obj2 = $obj2->where('status', 2);` before the `$obj1 = $obj1->where('status', 1);` and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$query1 = Celebrity::query();
$query2 = Celebrity::query();

$query1 = $query1->where('status', 1);
$query2 = $query2->where('status', 2);

$result1 = $query1->get();
$result2 = $query2->get();
```

you can add condition clause in this code.

Comment: its too produces the same result :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested using laravel 5.4 and it is working

```
use App\Models\Customer;

Route::get('/', function()
{
    $d1 = Customer::select('*');
    $d2 = Customer::select('*');

    $d1 = $d1->where('name', 'joseph');
    $d2 = $d2->where('name', 'dicdican');

    dd($d1->toSql(), $d2->toSql());
```

Results:

```
"select * from `customers` where `name` = ? and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null"

"select * from `customers` where `name` = ? and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

If you mind sharing the whole code block?

------ Updated

PHP Raw:

```
$s1 = 'hello';
$s2 = $s1;

$s2 = $s2.' welcome';

dd($s2, $s1);
```

Expected Results:

[image: response]

Comment: that causes it from appending.. somehow considered as expected output